# $ionicLoading.hide freezes all ionSpinner's animations on view

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using the **$ionicLoading** while loading content from a rest service and hiding the loading progress on ***then*** call of promise. 
This is done only the first time data is required.
Then I'm using pull to refresh (**ionRefresher**) to refresh data but the ionSpinner in the refresher is frozen (without animation). 
I think there is something wrong when in the call to ***$ionicLoading.hide()*** that freezes all ionSpinners in view. My platform is **android**. Here is an small example of this behavior using only an ionSpinner and $ionicLoading: http://codepen.io/oscarmesa/pen/EKyrMr

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic Loading</title>

  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.2.4/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Loading...</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app',['ionic'])
.config(function() {
  //Set platform UI to android
  ionic.Platform.setPlatform('android');
})
 .controller('myController',function($ionicLoading){
   $ionicLoading.show();
   setTimeout(function(){
     $ionicLoading.hide();
   },5000);
});
```

Comment: does my answer and codepen example address your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This fact that the Ionic spinner animations stall and exhibit this janky behavior at all is because of a design oversight by the Ionic team. If the stock spinners used **hardware accelerated 3D CSS transforms** to render the animation via GPU then they would *never* stall due to single-threaded JavaScript operations requiring time to process data and rebind the view. For all my apps I override the $ionicLoading element classes like so and I included ionRefresher styles for your scenario also:

```
.loading-container .loading {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: url(../images/icon-invert.svg) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 64px 64px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
.loading-container .loading .spinner { display: none; }

.scroll-refresher .icon-refreshing { 
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
.icon-refreshing .spinner { display: none; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(0deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(360deg); }
}
@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(0deg); transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(0deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg); transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(360deg); transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

Then to ensure the loading spinner is shown during code execution use a timeout:

```
$ionicLoading.show();
$timeout(function () {
  //execute all the expensive things that would grind the default spinner to a halt!
}, 200).then($ionicLoading.hide);
```

After seeing this in action your product owner will ask, "How did you find the time to port the entire app to some native script solution from an HTML5 hybrid Ionic app since your last round of deliverables?"

Codepen fork of your example with implemented solution: http://codepen.io/TaeKwonJoe/pen/jrwwjN

Check out this fantastic demo for more GPU animation inspiration:
http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit